# Removing specific section from thousands of pdfs (using python)

Tags: python, pdf

There is a case in my job where l have to remove a specific section (Glossary) from thousands of pdf documents.

The text l want to remove has a different font from the other parts:
Example:
"Floor"  the lower surface of a room, on which one may walk.
"exchange" an act of giving one thing and receiving another (especially of the same type or value) in return.

Can you please suggest a way how to do it faster?

Answer (score 2):

One of the possible ways to solve this problem is to find the section you want to delete using regex. Then using one of the libraries for pdf editing in python to delete this section.